# Do a condition as per situation in Appium

Tags: testing, automation, appium

I am new to Appium automation test framework and I have a condition. There is a pop-up which comes up if a file is not previously downloaded on the device. And if the pop-up comes I want to perform the operation on the pop-up. If pop-up doesn't come up i want to perform function on the next screen. I am confused about how to use the if condition to find if pop-up has come up or by finding the string on the pop-up. Currently the test is crashing as i have not handled the pop-up scenario. I am directly performing the function on the next screen. Please help me out. Attaching the screenshot of the pop-up

[image]

Comment: if u are using java .try catch will help

Comment: ok but how to check if the pop-up has come or not.. as the pop-up will come only if the Voice Coach is not downloaded. else it will not come..

Comment: within try block write only if condition, if the element not found it moves to catch block then handle exception some thing like this: try{ driver.switchto().window(pop1); if(driver.finele(by.id("id of your NOW/LATER ")).isdisplayed();{driver.findele(by.id().click()}} catch(Exception e){syso("old voice found")}

Comment: hey thanks i did it like this-  try {
            waitForElementToBeClickable(By.id("downloadNow"));
            driver.findElement(By.id("downloadNow")).click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.print("Voice coach already downloaded");
        }

Comment: but i didnt add if condition

Comment: if condition is to ensure weather pop up displayed or not , its displayed do some action , if it is working perfectly don't add if condition

Comment: Can you please tell me what should i put in place of window(pop1)?? I mean what will be the name of the pop up window exactly?? or what parameter i should pass there... because pop1 or any name gives an error that it cannot be resolved